# Find out Lipschitz constant L

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, matrix-multiplication, numerical-methods

I have an assignment in which I have to prove that the largest Lipschitz constant L for [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vz7it.png) this function in the link is λmax(ATranspose*A).I would be very grateful to anyone who helps.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule for an non-analytic matrix A (i.e. you don't have a way to get that value via classic mathematical analysis), you want to use the [Power Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration).